# Function in a class doesn't require self parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-typing, self

Trying to make a Python module which provides functions for user input.
My code looks like this:

```py
class PyInput:
    def inputString(prompt = "Enter a string: >>> "):
        userInput = input(prompt)
        return userInput
```

I'm receiving the following error when I run the function:

> Instance methods should take a "self" parameter

I have tried to add a self parameter to the function, but this requires the user to make an object of the class first, which isn't what I want.
Is there a way to define a function within a class that so it doesn't take a `self` parameter?

I'm running Python 3.11 on a [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11) 64-bit laptop.

Comment: Do you want that to be a _class method_? What's the point to having it in a class to begin with?

Comment: Regarding the first problem, you can decorate the function as `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` but the latter requires a "cls" parameter instead of "self".

Comment: `str(userInput)` doesn't do anything. It returna a string, but you don't do anything with the returned value. It's also unnecessary, since `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's in a class with a whole bunch of other functions, so it needs to be in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to define functions inside a class without the `self` parameter if you decorate it using `@staticmethod`. For example:

```
class Example:

    @staticmethod
    def answer():
        print('42')
```